# How do you exclude file extensions from command-line JSHint?

Tags: jshint

I'm trying to exclude `*.min.js` and `*.intellisense.js` files from being linted by [command-line jshint](http://jshint.com/docs/cli/). I'm passing in a [`.jshintignore`](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/examples/.jshintignore) file via `--exclude-path` that looks like this:

```
*.min.js
*.intellisense.js
**.min.js
**.intellisense.js
**/*.min.js
**/*.intellisense.js
**\*.min.js
**\*.intellisense.js
```

None of the patterns seem to be matching. Versions: Node v5.3.0, jshint v2.8.0.

The full command that I'm running (in a dir like `D:\Projects\SomeWeb\`):

`D:\utils\nodejs\node.exe D:\utils\nodejs\node_modules\jshint\bin\jshint --verbose --show-non-errors --exclude-path D:\utils\nodejs\.jshintignore .`

**Update #1:**
As a workaround, I'm using this powershell command:

```
powershell -nologo -noprofile -command "Get-ChildItem -Include *.js -Exclude *.min.js,*-vsdoc.js,*.intellisense.js -Recurse | % { D:\utils\nodejs\node D:\utils\nodejs\node_modules\jshint\bin\jshint --verbose --show-non-errors $_.FullName }"
```